# Azure IoT Hub - IoTHubTrigger Azure function doesn't execute if a route is set up on the IoT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have an IoTHubTrigger Azure function that processes the events from the IoT Hub.
It works as expected until I add a new Route in "Message routing" setting of the IoT Hub to send events to another event hub. In which case, the events successfully get routed to the event hub but don't hit the IoTHubTrigger Azure function anymore. Worth mentioning that the only options I have as endpoints to for route are Event Hubs, Service Bus Queue, Service Bus Topic and Storage.

Is there a way for me to have it route to both, the azure function and the event hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following route will forward all telemetry messages to the default endpoint such as a built-in iot hub endpoint **events**:

[image]

Comment: have a look at the documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-custom

Comment: I see! I totally missed that part. Thanks for your help!